# How can I delete all entries in a MySQL table that are NOT in a list of unique indexes?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has a unique index that is comprised of 3 different columns (system_id, file_name, and file _path).

I want to write a query that deletes ALL records in the table that is NOT IN a list of unique indexes... The problem is I don't know how to write a NOT IN clause that checks 3 columns at once... If I use 3 seperate NOT IN clauses (1 for each column) it will compare each entry in one column to each entry in another column...

So ideally, something like this exists... Where any entry that is not in that list is deleted.

```
DELETE FROM file_list WHERE unique_index NOT IN((1, "Name1", "Path1"), (2, "Name2", "Path2"));
```

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify indexes in `WHERE` clauses, you specify column names. The database figures out which index to use automatically (although it's possible to give it hints with optional query clauses).

You can use a list of column names when the `IN` list contains lists of values.

```
DELETE
FROM file_list
WHERE (system_id, file_name, file_path) NOT IN ((1, "Name1", "Path1"), (2, "Name2", "Path2"))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!